# return multiple strings from an array of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings

```
var arr = ['welcome', 'test', 'the', 'nothing'];
```

Now I want to find all strings that have 4 or more letters. I use the following code but it only returns one string.

```
  for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].length >= 4) {
     return arr[i];
  }
}
```

How can I return all strings with 4 or more letters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is precisely what [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for. The first example is nearly exactly what you want (7 letters instead of 4).

Comment: Please try searching before asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accumulate all matched objects into a array and return the array :

```
  let filteredArray =[];
  for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].length > 3) {
     filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
```

Or use a function : `let filteredArray = arr.filter(v => v.length > 3)`

Comment: How does this differ from the answer I already gave?

Comment: I answer with the original code and besides `arr.filter(v => v.length > 3)`  doesn't change `arr`. You don't assign the function result to a variable. So it is useless.

Comment: @peteb they are completely different: this uses a `for` loop, yours is using `filter`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That is an edit after my original comment. Also what about the `arr.filter()` part.

Comment: @peteb multiple similar answers are common place for trivial issues. Why so much concern?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const filterByLength = (arr, requiredLength) => {
  return arr.filter(v => v.length > requiredLength)
}

console.log(filterByLength(arr, 3)) // ['welcome', 'test', 'nothing']
```

Comment: `arr.filter(v => v.length > 3)`  doesn't change `arr`. You don't assign the function result to a variable. So it is useless.

Comment: This code is still not right. You still don't assign`filterByLength(arr, 3)` to a variable. This would be better like that for example : `const newArr = filterByLength(arr, 3)`

Comment: @davidxxx I'm aware that `filter()` returns a new Array instance and doesn't perform an inline mutation of the array `filter()` was called on. Since the question asked doesn't demonstrate the usage of the result, I opted to not assign it to some arbitrary variable and instead left it up to the asker to utilize the result however they saw fit. I updated my answer with a `console.log()` around the filtered array to better illustrate their is a new Array returned, per you commentary.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you `return` you are exiting the loop after it finds only one match.

Try this:

```js
let arr = ["this", "is", "longer", "than", "4"];
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].length >= 4) {
     console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could add it to a different array and use *that*

```js
    let arr = ["this", "is", "longer", "than", "4"],
    otherarr = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].length >= 4) {
         otherarr.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(otherarr);
```

Or you could simplify by using the `Array.filter` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
let arr = ["this", "is", "longer", "than", "4"];
console.log(
  arr.filter(function(array_element) {
    return array_element.length >= 4;
  })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Javascript's `Array.filter()` method.

`arr.filter(string => string.length > 4)`